# Celery 5.0.4 with Django 3.1.4 - OperationalError: Error 101 connecting to localhost:6379. Network is unreachable

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, redis, celery

I am having an issue with Django and Celery integration whereby it seems the settings for the `RESULT_BACKEND` and `BROKER_URL` keys are not being honored.

I am running Django and Celery successfully in Docker with `django-celery-beat` without issue. Scheuduled tasks are running as expected.

The issue I am having is when calling a `@task` function through a Django Signal.
When this runs (triggered from Django Rest Framework); I get the following error:

`OperationalError: Error 101 connecting to localhost:6379. Network is unreachable.`

This would be expected because I dont run redis locally but within another container.
Any ideas on why the configuration is not being used?

**I have confirmed that the environment variables are being loaded correctly and seen by both celery and Django.**

**Compose File**

```
app-redis-prod:
  image: redis:alpine
     
app-worker-prod:
  environment:
    - PLATFORM=prod
    - CERT_DIR=/run/certificates
    - DB_SSL_MODE=require
    - BROKER_URL=redis://rocx-redis-prod:6379
    - RESULT_BACKEND=redis://rocx-redis-prod:6379
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('BROKER_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('RESULT_BACKEND', 'redis://localhost:6379')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

**celery.py**

```
app = Celery('MYAPP')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f"Request {self.request!r}")
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have proper environment variables in app container ?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the environment is all setup correctly. 

>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL
'redis://rocx-redis-prod:6379'
>>> settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND
'redis://rocx-redis-prod:6379'

Comment: You have shown info regarding worker container which from your info seems to function correctly and not the app container where error occurs, to be more concrete your task is created in redis by app container to be later consumed by worker

Comment: The worker and app containers are exactly the same in terms of configuration; both have the correct environment variables set.

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong with configuration on app container as it is trying to connect to localhost:6379 which is default  in your settings, bash in it interactively and check it out.  If you added environment variables later you might just need to restart of docker container

Comment: Celery 5, is full of bugs, try with Celery 4. I had same issues, at the end it was an error caused by consumer Celery

Comment: @iklinac - I did change the defaults to the same as what's set in the environment with the same result so its coming from somewhere else or its not reading the variables to begin with. I'll try a different version as suggested by MaximeK

Comment: @iklinac - I rebuilt the apache envvars file and its working now so you were right! Thank for the help! Could you mark your comment as an answer so I could mark it as solved?

Comment: I will answer on your behalf.